# indoor positioning system : how can i get the user location at airport floor level and wayfinding using wi-fi access points?

Tags: node.js, progressive-web-apps, indoor-positioning-system

Indoor positioning  system: how can I get the user geolocation, not using GPS, at airport floor level and wayfinding using wi-fi access points?
Is it possible to get longitude/ latitude on passing MAC address of Wi-Fi Access Points?

for technology nodejs server side and Angular at front end

Comment: There is no way in the browser to get the mac address of the WiFi access point you're connected to. If performance isn't an issue, you could potentially use something like traceroute on the server to get the location of the device, and which access point it is connected to, then you could look up the lat/long for that access point...

Comment: can we detect user location (longitude and latitude) using wi-fi access points through mobile wi-fi on using angular PWA in a browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way in the browser to get the mac address of the WiFi access point you're connected to. If performance isn't an issue, you could potentially use something like traceroute on the server to get the location of the device, and which access point it is connected to, then you could look up the lat/long for that access point...

But in short, there are no APIs in the browser that will get you the user location using wifi access points through mobile wifi.

Comment: Thank you PeteLe. is it possible in case of native mobile App to get user location using Wi-Fi access points through mobile Wi-Fi and no GPS? or your other suggestion to implementing wayfinding in a mall or airport in case of Indoor positioning system?